# How to check if cassandra is up and running using initContainers

Tags: kubernetes, cassandra

In my kubernetes cluster, I have cassandra statefulset which is using `cassandra:4.0` image. I want my application pods to wait for cassandra to be up & running first.

I suppose this can be done by adding an `initContainers` in application pod deployment. The initContainer will check the status of cassandra thereby blocking the application pod from starting till it assures the availability of cassandra.

I don't know how to create such initContainer for checking the status of cassandra statefulset, I've checked onthe web but didn't find any examples related to cassandra.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Note: I'm not using the [actual cassandra image](https://hub.docker.com/_/cassandra) and not this example one (`gcr.io/google-samples/cassandra:v13`)

Comment: Because SO is not a consultancy; if you had attempted something, and it was producing an error, we can help you troubleshoot. But I find the idea highly suspicious that there were no results when searching the web (or even SO) for how one checks the status of cassandra. There's also likely some NIH going on since there are multiple _managed_ cassandra mechanisms, either helm charts or dedicated operators, getting you out of that job entirely or -- to answer your own question -- showing how _they_ do what you are asking

Comment: @mdaniel Thanks for your suggestion, but I think you either didn't ready my question carefully or misunderstood it.
**getting you out of that job entirely  -** I don't use helm & neither my question mentions helm. Also helm charts and dedicated operators comes with a lot of stuff you may not want. Also helm charts will install the cassandra in its release scope, you will still want your application pods to check the status
**showing how they do what you are asking -** Can you specify the link, I'm expecting app pods using initContainers for checking the status

Comment: Why would you want to wait for cassandra to start? Why not try to implement app level check, or just let the app to run and fail connecting - k8s will restart the app and use exponetial backoff for pod, and it will keep trying until it succeeds.

Comment: @Matt **why wait?** good question, because app does not check the connection in its startup phase and I've no control over application's codebase. So pod will not fail unless the application tries to connect to cassandra on a specific event.

Comment: I came up with this: `while [[ $(nodetool status -h <cassandraservice> | grep UN) != 0 ]]; do; sleep 1; done`. It should wait for at least one cassandra node to be UP and Normal before continuing. You run is as a script in initContainer. I didn't test it so I cannot guarantee it will work but I think I saw somebody using something simmilar to this.

Answer (score 1):

Using a similar approach to the Cassandra Helm Chart readiness probe:

```yaml
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      initContainers:
      - name: check-cassandra-ready
        image: cassandra:3.11
        command: ['sh', '-c', 
          'until nodetool -h <cassandra-host> status | grep -E "^UN\\s+${POD_IP}";
          do echo waiting for cassandra; sleep 2; done;']
```

Your Cassandra version must be the same as the nodetool version.

Comment: It helps but I needed to start cassandra nodes with JMX enabled in order to get nodetool connected remotely. Otherwise It fails with error: "connection refused"

Answer (score -1):

You could Wait for cassandra Service to be created, using a shell one-line command like:

```
for i in {1..100}; do sleep 1; if dig cassandraservice; then exit 0; fi; done; exit 1
```

Ref: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/

Comment: Cassandra service? maybe. But the OP wants to wait for cassadra pods to be ready and running, not for creation of a service.